# duplicate SSMS menues after VS2022 install

Tags: visual-studio-2019, ssms, visual-studio-2022

[image: Duplicate menu names]

Hey Folks, I got this double menu thing happening after I installed VS2022 alongside VS2019. I want to keep both because VS2022 does not have any SSIS extension.  Other than installing only one VS version, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I've installed multiple Visual Studios over the years and don't have this problem; I wouldn't be surprised if the fact your installed VS 2022 was little more than a coincidence.

Comment: might be yes. It kept adding menu names as I made modifications to my VS though. Maybe having the data tools package on both is the problem?

Comment: Try repairing your SSMS install... or even an uninstall/reinstall of SSMS (I also have multiple VS installs, including previews, without this happening to SSMS).

Comment: yup, reinstallation worked! Thanks Richard

Answer (score 0):

to fix the problem, I did what Richard suggested and uninstalled SSMS. A repair did not work. So, the solution (for me) if you need to use SSIS but still want to upgrade to VS2022 would be:

1. Uninstall SSMS
2. Install VS2022 but keep 2019
3. Reinstall SSMS

Et voilà!